# Lots of DNS lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, php, javascript

Our internal application website that is hosted on a LAMP is very slow to load.

With firebug, we get this : [image]

Most of those files are .js and everything is on the same domain. We can't find why there are so many DNS Lookup, it's insane !

Can you please help us ? Thanks !

Comment: Id the graph you posted showing DNS lookups, because I don't see that?

Comment: The DNS lookups are in blue.

Comment: Is the graph showing a single connection\session to the web site?

Comment: how many js\css files are there and now are they included in the webpages?

Comment: @joeqwerty: yes only one connection
@Sage: the php is the first one, everything else is about 6 css and .js files. As far as I know, they are all included.

Comment: Well my suggestion at this point would be to run a packet capture on the client and see what all of the DNS lookups are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the **KeepAlive** was at **off** on the Apache conf, this partially solve our issue because now our website isn't working on Chrome/Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/146052/only-receiving-one-document-at-a-time-from-new-web-server/) where someone had a similar issue, turned out it was iptables causing a bottleneck. Turn off any firewalls and see what you get!

Comment: Thx but I already saw this post and tried, no luck :(